# Updated - How to interact with a button that I can't get using python-selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, iframe

## New version

I want go through the Terms and Conditions popup message shown at this [link](https://beacon.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=1015&LayerID=21105&PageTypeID=2), whether clicking the "Agree" button or the "X" button to close the window, usign python-selenium.

After some feedbacks, I know now that I'm not dealing with an iframe but the problem is that I can't get any of those buttons, seems that I have to change the focus or something similar.

```
#======================
#Sets libraries
#======================
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains
import time
from datetime import datetime

#======================
#Gets into the webpage and breaks the captcha
#======================
#Sets chr_options to pass the cloudflare captcha
chr_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chr_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chr_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) #Hides selenium browser features
chr_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False) #Hides selenium browser features
chr_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled") #Hides testing browser features
chr_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions') #Disable extensions which may carry scripts
chr_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') #Disable developer/sandbox mode
chr_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars') #Disable information bar
chr_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') #Disable memory optimization features
chr_options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation') #Disable memory optimization features
chr_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') #Disable graphic features

#Sets the webdriver
chrdr_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_service=Service(executable_path=chrdr_path)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service,options=chr_options)

#Opens 2 pages in the browser to simulate human behaviour
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://beacon.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=1015&LayerID=21105&PageTypeID=2&PageID=9036', '_blank')")
#Waits 15 seconds
time.sleep(15)
#Moves to beacon schneider window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
#Goes to the captcha frame
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
#Clicks on the chaptcha checkbox
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="challenge-stage"]/div/label/input').click()

#Here I found the popup message which doens't let me pass
time.sleep(20)
# WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Agree'")))
popup_button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Agree']")
popup_button.click()
```

In the last lines I've been increasing the time, setting explicit waits, setting different waiting methods (for presence and clickability) but it always crashes on the line that searches for `By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Agree']"`

Seems pretty straight-forward but I don't seem to get how to solve this

## Original Version

I want to click the "Agree" button on this message, which I think is an iframe, on this [site](https://beacon.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=1015&LayerID=21105&PageTypeID=2&PageID=9036) to fetch some data.

[image: picture of the popup I want to get through]

The first problem I have is that I don't really know what I'm dealing with.

At the beginning this page uses a cloudflare captcha to filter out bots, this was passed thanks to this [video](https://youtu.be/Sur4OSC5KW4?si=oYnFXNJLF7kqwc2P).

This what I've tried so far:

1. Reach the button through its container (classname "modal-footer" and xpath `//*[@id="appBody"]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]`)
2. Wait until the presence of message's title (classname "close")
3. Wait until message's "X" button is clickable (classname "close" and xpath `//*[@id="appBody"]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/button/span`)
4. Count the iframes on the page so then I can use move_to statement with index argument

A good approach might be using EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it but I don't know how to refer to the frame.

I've noticed some things that might be of interest:

1. The iframe I think I'm dealing with is height=1, width=1, visibility: hidden as style attribute and it's located in the upper left corner of the popup window I'm trying to interact with.
2. Below the iframe's tags is a script hosted at [link](https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js/v84a3a4012de94ce1a686ba8c167c359c1696973893317)

Any advice on how solve this or in what direction I should be pointing to would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance,
Antonio

Comment: Right-click on the "Agree" button and choose Inspect. From there, find that button in the DOM and move up the tree until you get to either an IFRAME or the HTML tag. If you don't hit an IFRAME, then the button isn't in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was able to find the page you were on... at least it seems to be the same or similar. I inspected the Agree button and found that it was not in an IFRAME. The XPath below will find that button.

```
//a[text()='Agree']
```

It basically just looks for an A tag that contains the text "Agree".

---

Your code was missing a wait for clickable for the Agree button. You have a wait commented out but the locator was not complete so it was failing. I removed unneeded code, added the wait back in, and fixed the locator. The code below is working.

```
#Opens 2 pages in the browser to simulate human behaviour
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://beacon.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=1015&LayerID=21105&PageTypeID=2&PageID=9036', '_blank')")
#Moves to beacon schneider window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
#Goes to the captcha frame
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
#Clicks on the chaptcha checkbox
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="challenge-stage"]/div/label/input').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content    
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Agree']"))).click()
```

Comment: As in previuos answer, you are also right, it's not in the iframe. Tried this but didn't work. The error log says that there is no such element

Comment: I know this works because it works for me. There's something about the way you are using it that isn't correct. Edit your question and post a [mcve] that represents the simplest code you are using to click this element.

Comment: Hey @JeffC the post is updated, please give a check when possible

Comment: The problem with the code you posted is that you don't have a wait. You have a wait commented out but the locator in that wait is missing the final bracket in my answer. I've updated my answer with the working code.

Comment: You were right on the code I posted, I don't know why I missed that last bracket, I ran it correctly before several times. Nevertheless I followed your advice, did the change and it didn't work, you can check this link https://ibb.co/wgG5k3X

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention... I don't see the captcha so I had to comment those lines out. The thing you are missing is that after switching to the IFRAME, you never switch back to default content. I added that line in my answer. Try that and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: You were right. What I was missing was to switch to default content. I'll update the thread! Thanks @JeffC

Comment: Update the thread? If my code solved the issue, then this is the answer to the question posted. If you have additional questions, you'll need to post them as completely new questions. Additional or new questions are not allowed to be edited into an existing question because it will cause confusion, etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm used to use THIS as a knowledge base but not to ask myself, by that I don't really know the rules.

Comment: Fair enough... my suggestion would be to read the help topics. That will help you better understand the rules, how to get the most out of the site, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `Agree` button on the webpage is NOT inside an Iframe.
It seems you are getting element visibility issue.
Use `explicit wait` and wait for element to be clickable.
Use following css selector to identify the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".modal-dialog a.button-1"))).click()
```

Need to import following libraries as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: You are right, it's not in the iframe. Tried it but didn't work. The error log says that there is no such element

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Agree</kbd> button is not inside an `IFRAME`, so you no need to worry about dealing with IFRAME to click on the desired button.

Refer the below code to click on the button using [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://beacon.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=1015&LayerID=21105&PageTypeID=2&PageID=9036')

# Create a wait object with 10s wait time
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

# Click on Agree cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Agree']"))).click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: As in previuos answers, you are also right, it's not in the iframe. Also tried this but didn't passed trough

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using an extension to Selenium?

In full disclosure, I'm the author of [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/). This package is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

As some of the other answers point out, the cookie banner isn't wrapped in an iframe. Maybe something like this would work?

```py
from browserist import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://beacon.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=1015&LayerID=21105&PageTypeID=2&PageID=9036")
    browser.click.button("//div[@class='modal-footer']//a[text()='Agree']")
```

If you wanted to engage with elements inside an iframe element and hereafter come back to the origin page, it's fairly easy. Example on how to continue your script with [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/):

```py
    browser.iframe.switch_to("//iframe[@id='id-of-iframe']")
    browser.click.button("//xpath/to/button/inside/iframe")
    browser.iframe.switch_to_original_page()
```

[Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) also has a [built-in method to handle cookie banners](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/user-guide/combo-methods/cookie-banner/), which makes it much more scalable and easier to read. You can refactor the example above to this:

```py
from browserist import Browser, CookieBannerSettings

accept_cookies = CookieBannerSettings(
    url="https://beacon.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=1015&LayerID=21105&PageTypeID=2&PageID=9036",
    button_xpath="//div[@class='modal-footer']//a[text()='Agree']"
)

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.combo.cookie_banner(accept_cookies)
```

Notes:

- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) doesn't need explicit conditions like `WebDriverWait`, `expected_conditions` or `element_to_be_clickable` – it's already built in so you don't have to worry about it. Instead, [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) awaits an element to be fully loaded before it interacts with it. More on this concept [here](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/#difference-from-selenium).

Comment: Your soluction is pretty promising but I couldn't make it work, I think that this could be because of the catcha handling that must be done as soon as the page is open... That level of simplicity would be amazing

Comment: True, I sometimes meet the "Cloudfare CAPTCHA guardian" that's near impossible to pass as well. Just to be sure: If you use Selenium straight without Browserist, do you similarly meet that screen?

Comment: Yes, I thought that after beating the captcha everything will go down-hill